# Low level delegatecalls from contract to deployed library issues

Tags: storage, delegatecall, libraries

I'm looking to make low-level delegatecall to a library that can be changed via a setter on the contract(see code below). Within the library, I am looking to make state changes to the calling contract. I have two issues.

First, I am unable to pass a storage struct to the delagatecall function correctly. The call below to updateStruct fails. I am aware of abi encoding difference between libraries vs contracts (https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/contracts.html#function-signatures-and-selectors-in-libraries). From the docs I have applied "Other storage pointer types use the type identifier of their corresponding non-storage type, but append a single space followed by storage to it." So in the code below I am doing exactly that `abi.encodeWithSignature("updateStruct(Test.A storage)", refType)`. Why is this not correct?

Second, I am trying to update the state of the value type like uint in the updateUint function. Is that possible via a delegatecall to lib? The code below does not fail when calling updateUint but it does not update the valueType state variable of the calling contract.

Any help appreciated

```
library Test{

    struct A {
        uint256 a;
    }
    function updateStruct(A storage refType)external {
        refType.a=5;
    }

    function updateUint(uint256 valueType)external {
        valueType=5;
    }
}

contract TestContract {
    address public adapterLib;
    struct A {
        uint256 a;
    }
    A public refType;
    uint public valueType;

    function setLib(address lib)public{
        adapterLib = lib;
    }
    

    function updateStruct()public {
        (bool success, bytes memory result)=adapterLib.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("updateStruct(Test.A storage)", refType));
        require(success);
    }

    function updateUint()public {
        (bool success, bytes memory result)=adapterLib.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("updateUint(uint256)", valueType));
        require(success);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/103395/66634 Similar post here, see if this works?

Answer (score 3):

I think the best approach is to have a Library function that modifies your contract's storage. (By using `assembly{ }`)

Basically, instead of sending a structure by `delegatecall` and then receiving it in the Library, you rather send the storage slot of the struct and appropriately modify the data in that slot.

See the code below for reference.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENCED
pragma solidity 0.8.3;  

    struct A {
        uint256 a;
    }


library TestLibrary {

    function updateStruct(A storage refType) external {
        refType.a = 5;
    }

    function updateOverDelegateCall(uint256 slotNumber) external {

        assembly {
        sstore(slotNumber, 9)
        }

    }

}

contract TestContract {

    using TestLibrary for A; 

    A public refType;

    address public adapterLib;

    function setLib(address lib)public{
        adapterLib = lib;
    }


    function updateStruct() public {
        refType.updateStruct();
    }

    function updateOverDelegateCall() public {

        uint256 slotNumber;

        // Slot number of the struct we want to change
        assembly{
            slotNumber:=refType.slot
        }
        
        (bool success, bytes memory result)=adapterLib.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("updateOverDelegateCall(uint256)", slotNumber));
        require(success);
    }

}
```

The same approach can be done for any `unit`, `string` or any other type of value.

Comment: Hey cheers for you answer! I guess in order to update a value type like uint one has indeed no choice but to use assembly. However one should be ably to encode structs as pointers via encodeWithSignature while making a delegatecall without any assembly to input the slot explictly. Any idea why the above in my example does not work? I am referring to updateStruct()

Comment: I did try to solve it using Struct, but everything I tried (Sending Tupple), simply didn't work. And I can't figure out what the trick is.

Comment: Yeah me neither, will leave this question as open for now